# CakePHP: passing a variable to a view

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I basically want to echo the number of articles on the articles index template page. I have a method in the controller. How do I echo the result of that method in the index page?

Controller

```
public function articleCount()
{
    $article_count = $this->Articles->find('all')->count();
    $this->set('article_count',$article_count );
}
```

index

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 widget">
    <div class="panel panel-red panel-widget">
            <div class="row no-padding">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-5 widget-left">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-7 widget-right">
                    <div class="large"><?= echo article count here! ?></div>
                    <div class="text-muted">Categories</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Im fairly new to cakephp and would appreciate any help you can give

Comment: Read book.cakephp.org and do the tutorials, this is *very basic* stuff that is covered by the book. Read it from the beginning and do the tutorials. They'll teach the basics.

Comment: I have actually completed the tutorials. I am finding the book a little tricky but will go through it more thorughly

Answer (score 0):

The code you used needs to be in the index action, in the Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    // ...
    $article_count = $this->Articles->find('all')->count();
    $this->set('article_count',$article_count );
    // ...
}
```

Once you've done that, you can use the $article_count variable:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 widget">
    <div class="panel panel-red panel-widget">
            <div class="row no-padding">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-5 widget-left">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-7 widget-right">
                    <div class="large"><?= echo $article_count ?></div>
                    <div class="text-muted">Categories</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Nick!! that actually makes a lot of sense. I've been trying to crack this for ages

Comment: You're welcome!
Take a little time to learn how the routing works, it'll save you some headaches: /controller/action/$param1/$param2...

Comment: Sorry to move into another question but if I wanted to echo the number of categories from a seperate categories table how would i go about it?

Comment: Well, the same way as this, just use the Categories table, set the variable, and echo that.
$categories_count = $this->Categories->find('all')->count();

Comment: What I mean was how to access the categories table from the articles controller. I have since found out that I can use loadModel and then do as you said. Thanks for all the help! :)